# Django Forbidden (CSRF token missing.)

Tags: html, django, django-csrf

I am facing a problem to submit a text in Django. When I click Insert, the message Forbidden (CSRF token missing.):  appears. Can somebody help me?

Normally the csrf token is supposed to work.

I put the CSRF token in the html file, but still no working. I do not know if the csrf is in the wrong part of the code or not.

```
> <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
> {% csrf_token %}
>      <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
>     </form>
>     <div class="modal-content" hx-target="this" hx-swap="outerHTML" id="this">
> {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
> 
> <!-- Modal Header -->
>         <div class="modal-header">
>         <h4 class="modal-title">Show gabarit</h4>
>         <button type="button" class="close" data dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
>         </div>
> 
> <!-- Modal body -->
>         <div class="modal-body">
>               <pre style="font-size: 12px"><textarea id='input-text' name='input-text' style='height:100px;      width: 800px;'>{{commande}}</textarea></pre>
> 
> if formset %} 
>             <button class="mb-2 btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2"
> id="variables-button" type="button" onclick="openModal()">Variables</button>
> endif %}
> 
> 
>               <div id="modal" style="display:none;">
>                   <div id="variables-container"></div>
>                   <button class="mb-2 btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" 
> id="insert-button" type="button" onclick="closeModal()">Insérer</button>
>               </div>
>             </form>
> 
>             <div id='result'></div>
> 
>         </div>
> 
> 
>      </div>
> 
>     </div>
> 
> 
>     <script>
> function openModal() {
> var inputText = document.getElementById("input-text").value;
> var variableNames = inputText.match(/{(.*?)}/g);
> var variablesContainer = document.getElementById("variables-container");
> variablesContainer.innerHTML = "";
> for (var i = 0; i < variableNames.length; i++) {
> var variableName = variableNames[i].slice(1, -1);
> variablesContainer.innerHTML += "<div><label for='variable-" + variableName + "'>" + variableName + ":</label><input type='text' id='variable-" + variableName + "' name='variable-" + variableName + "'></div>";
>       }
> document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "block";
>     }
> 
> function closeModal() {
> var inputText = document.getElementById("input-text").value;
> var variableNames = inputText.match(/{(.*?)}/g);
> for (var i = 0; i < variableNames.length; i++) {
> var variableName = variableNames[i].slice(1, -1);
> var variableValue = document.getElementById("variable-"+ variableName).value;
> inputText = inputText.replace(variableNames[i], variableValue);
>       }
> document.getElementById("input-text").value = inputText;
> document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "none";
> document.getElementById("variables-button").style.display = "none";
> 
> var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
> xhr.open("POST", "{% url 'gabarits:save-variables-text' %}", true); 
> xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
> xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
> if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
> console.log("Input text saved successfully.");
>              }
> 
>           };
> xhr.send("text=" + inputText);
>         }
>     </script>
```

On the view side:

```
def save_variables_text(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST.get('text')
        InputText.objects.create(text=text)
    return render(request, 'previsualise.html')
```

Comment: Those template tags are very strange -- they are all missing the opening `{%` bracket.  i.e. you have `csrf_token %} ` but it is supposed to be `{% csrf_token %} `.

Comment: Also you can disable `csrf_token` requirement just using `@csrf_exempt` decorator but anyway I would at your place make this view more secure because ANYBODY can send request to this endpoint (using bot or postman) and make bunch of records in the database.